# Want to implement design pattern to save data to DB or Kafka based on configuration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter, mediator

I want to implement a design pattern to save data to DB or Kafka based on the configuration. For example if config value isDB=1 then save to DB else save to Kafka.

I was thinking to implement it using mediator pattern but not very sure on implementation part.

Comment: We're not a design or coding service. Please try to implement the mediator pattern yourself and, if you get stuck, come here with code you've written and we'll gladly help.

Comment: This should give you a fighting chance: `IStorage storage = DB == 1 ? new DBStorage() : new KafkaStorage();`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement those two persistence mechanisms using a common interface. Something like this:

```
interface IPersistence{
   Task SaveAsync(IEnumerable<Foo> entries);
}

class DbPersistence : IPersistence { /* implementation here */ }
class KafkaPersistence : IPersistence { /* implementation here */ }
```

at bootstrap time, you can read from a config file which persistence system you want and use a Dependency Injection library (like the one coming out of the box from .NET) to register the proper implementation.

Things would be of course different if you want this choice to be made at *runtime* instead. In that case I would use either the Strategy or the Factory pattern.